# “Operation system not found” after fresh Ubuntu Server installation

Tags: boot, software-installation, bootloader

I have just freshly installed Ubuntu Server 20.04.1 amd64 on my Laptop and did the most basic setup possible. Then when the installation was successful i was prompted to remove my installation medium (USB stick) and rebooted the system.

When the system then booted from the harddrive i just get the single line "Operation system not found" (not a typo, it actually says "Operation"). I then did the procedure once again and eyeballed that i correctly pick my harddrive to format and it went the same way. I can't do anything after restarting.

I then also tried to use Boot-Repair-x64 to repair the GRUB bootloader and it all went fine and sayd it repaired grub but in the end nothing changed. I'm trying for a full 5 hours now and I don't know what i should do. The Laptop is definitely working as i had my windows server as well as a suse-server running fine on there. Laptop is a Dell XPS L502X with an Intel i7-2630QM.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Edit: I am aware that another user asked a question like this 7 years ago where there was an answer like "Ubuntu 13 has some firmware issues". But it cannot possibly be still having those issues, or does it?

Screenshot of Gparted from comments:

[image]

Comment: I am using the laptop as a home-server because i don't need it anymore as a laptop

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/p7Ts2UF

Comment: I have added the screenshot to your question. This is not what I expected. I don't work with servers, so I can't tell you what's wrong. Hopefully someone else will. Best of luck.

Comment: I think there is a problem with your first partition.  Since your disk appears to use the MBR partitioning scheme, I suggest that you use the Disks app in a live desktop session to format (erase) the hard drive and use the GPT partitioning scheme.  Then perform the system installation.

Comment: The `bios_grub` partition leads me to believe this is a BIOS based computer with a GPT partitioning scheme.  It is weird the file system shows as *grub2 core.img*.  I would expect it to be blank or 'unknown'.  I don't use gparted though.

Comment: Can I use the Ubuntu-Live-Server image to partition the disk as GPT or do I first have to flash a Ubuntu-Live-Desktop image on my flashdrive? @Nmath

Answer (score 0):

Check the boot order.  On UEFI based computers, the server installer will re-order the boot options so the installation media is first.  That means it is probably trying to boot from the USB stick first, which has been removed.

Comment: The boot order is unchanged, It tries to boot from internal harddrive first and then from the USB. I even tried to manually boot directly from the harddrive which yielded the same results. When hitting enter during the boot error message it attempts to boot the next mediums in order which is then my usb flashdrive. But even when the flashdrive is not plugged in it doesn't work